# google maps android api error authorization failure app displaying blank map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hey i am building a project and trying to use google maps in it. I have been following the tutorial on the google developers site but when i run the map it comes up blank and i get the following error
google maps android api error authorization failure

my xml code for the map is

my java code for the map is 
    package com.example.travelni2;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class maps extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    }
}
```

and i have used the follwing information in my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.travelni2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".maps"
            android:label="@string/maps_title">
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCZK3F-UK0T_sUipWTAjmSzhZBr276rFuU"/>
    </application>



<permission
        android:name="com.example.project.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.project.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

I have creaed the api key using the google api console and have linked both it and google play services to my project

Comment: any help or advise on this would be gratly appreciated

Comment: follow this: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

I got the sample GoogleMaps applications to work by using my generated "Key for browser applications" instead of the "Key for Android applications". This might not be a long term solution but if you just want to get your app up and running it could work.